# Tomee - slf4j create logs file but not writing on them

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, log4j, slf4j, apache-tomee

I want to use log4j for my app (I don't need to handle the server logs for now). I searched for a solution but all post are related with server logs. When I run the app, the log4j.properties is read and the logs file are created but it didn't write on them.

I'm using Tomee as server. I have other project with Wildfly using the same solution for log4j and it works.

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.TEST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TEST.File = /opt/share/test-project/logs/test.log
log4j.appender.TEST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.TEST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TEST.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{ISO8601}] %5p - %x - %c.%M(%L): %m%n

# Define the types of logger and level of logging    
#log4j.rootLogger.org = DEBUG,CONSOLE
log4j.logger.com.test=DEBUG, TEST
```

Log4jConfig class which is initialized:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

@WebListener
public class Log4jConfig implements ServletContextListener {


    private final static String LO4G_FILENAME="/opt/share/test-project/config/log4j.properties"; 
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jConfig.class);

...
...
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
    { 

        try{
            File file = new File(LO4G_FILENAME);
            if (file.exists())
            {
                PropertyConfigurator.configure(LO4G_FILENAME);
                LOGGER.info("[Log4JInitServlet - contextInitialized] - Log4J configured:"+LO4G_FILENAME);
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("[Log4JInitServlet - contextInitialized] - Exception >>",e);
        }

    }

}
```

Test.java:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("/test")
public class TestWs {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestWs.class.getName());
    //here LOGGER is null. If I put it into test() is not null but not write on the log either.

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test(){

        LOGGER.debug("[TestWs - init] - init");
        long currentSystemTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        LOGGER.error("[TestWs - test] - Error: TEST");
        LOGGER.debug("[TestWs - test] - Finish Timing:"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-currentSystemTime));

        return Response.ok().build();

    }
}
```

POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade dependency of slf4f :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```

use `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(class-name.class);` into class in which you want to create logs.

use bellow log4j configuration :-

Root logger option

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
```

Direct log messages to a log file

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.com.amstech=DEBUG
```

Comment: thanks, I needed to add/upgrade the slf4j-log4j12 dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of all the setup but if you put log4j lib/config in the container you can need to set in conf/system.properties:

```
openejb.logger.external=true
```

otherwise (for legacy reasons), tomee will setup log4j in a custom way making your configuration not respected. This property just means "use normal log4j behavior".